# How do bind Command-b to move back by a word in iTerm/ZSH?

Tags: zsh, iterm2

I just installed iTerm and have ZSH because I have Catalina.

I used to have Bash and Catalina instead, and an iTerm installation on a different laptop that I have gradually configured over the years.

So I can't remember the specific steps I took to get ⌘-b/⌘-f to work as `backward-word`/`forward-word` in Bash. And trying to search for a combination of possible keywords (binding, mapping, emacs mode, zsh, iterm, etc.) didn't yield an answer to this question.

I copied over the `.inputrc` from my previous machine but that hasn't helped.

What are the steps necessary here? Is it a combination of Zsh settings along with iTerm key binding settings?

Comment: Good question, wrong site: SO is for programming problems, so your question should go to i.e. [superuser](https://superuser.com/).